# using a group by and summing a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following date in one table

```
Id     Side    Quant
ABC    B       10
ABC    S       5
ABC    B       2
XYZ    B       3
XYZ    B       1
MNO    S       6
```

I would like to have a query that groups by ID and sums the quantity. When summing the quantity where the Side equals S the quantity needs to be subtracted (so a negative value). The result should look like below,

```
ID    Quant
ABC   7
XYZ   4
MNO   -6
```

I know I can do something like below but not sure how to deal with Sides that are equal to S having to be negative?

```
select ID, Sum(Quant) TotalQuant from tblOrders
group by ID, Quant
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN` to negate numbers:

```
SELECT ID,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Side = 'S' THEN -Quant ELSE Quant END) AS TotalQuant
FROM tblOrders
GROUP BY ID
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383104)**</kbd>

With **SQL Server 2012+** you can use **`IIF`** function

```
SELECT ID,
   SUM(IIF(Side = 'S', -Quant, Quant)) AS TotalQuant
FROM tblOrders
GROUP BY ID
```